# Using Firebase Functions with Express.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a function that accepts input from an API endpoint. But the problem is when  I now want to insert the records into the database. Immediately I add the **async** before the function I get an eslint error of **Parsing Error: Unexpected token =>**. Because of this, I cannot deploy the function. Kindly also look at the attached screenshot

```js
app.post("/c2b/confirm", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("----------confirm-------------");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  const payment = admin.firestore().collection("payments").doc();
  await payment.set(req.body);
  res.status(200).json({"ResultCode": 0, "ResultDesc": "Success"});
});

exports.main = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a linter error.
Please, be sure you have these in your eslintrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },

  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8
  }
}
```